# how to query a collection based on value of a field array in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following user schema

```
{
        "__v" : 26,
        "_id" : ObjectId("52b47058fe5e3493a2cf8365"),
        "live_sockets" : [
                "CEGok0rSz2UtBIHX9DlV",
                "s6M45OA0MDBs4aGL9DlW",
                "2XiszSuyiPAGr-Ga9ZCN",
                "lIFNEeUgXRB6tgvP9ZCO",
                "JPtzQOD_52maf6VS9gtb",
                "kDL06aXiI8WWlig19gtc",
                "75Bt5p6WqgmRcyer9xSm",
                "Ge_sKLen32Q91wLW9xSn",
                "EpHt3qju34GTZevU_Bsd",
                "n0hq0EQAjJOptxdy_qEB",
        ],
        "name" : {
                "first" : "Test",
                "last" : "User"
        },
        "notifications_count" : 0,
        "role" : 1
}
```

How can i query a user based on a particular live socket as socket_ids are unique. 
If i have a variable called current_socket_id how can i find a user which the socket belongs to..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.find({"live_sockets" : {$in : [socketId]}},{"name" : 1,"_id":0})
```

Will give the name for the socket id